# Aligning an equation

Tags: equations, align

I have an equation like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\ 
|a+bi|^2=a^2+b^2\\
|a+bi|^2=(a+bi)(a+bi)\\
        =(a+bi)(a-bi)\\
        =a^2+b^2i^2\\
        =a^2+b^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

the resualt looks like this:

[image]

How can I align this equation, that all of `=` symbols to be under each other

Comment: You need a `&` before each `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is preferable to use the [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package for this task; you should use an `\lvert`/`\rvert` construction for the delimiters. With `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, you can automatically scale the delimiters by using the starred version (`\abs*`). Also, I have created a macro for the imaginary symbol; then you can change it all the way through just by changing the definition of the marco.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand*\imag{i} % change 'i' to '\mathrm{i}' if you want an upright 'i'

\begin{document}

\noindent No equation number:
\begin{align*}
  \abs{a + b\imag}
  &= \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}},\\
  \abs{a + b\imag}^{2}
  &= a^{2} + b^{2},\\
  \abs{a + b\imag}^{2}
  &= (a + b\imag)(a + b\imag)\\
  &= (a + b\imag)(a - b\imag)\\
  &= a^{2} + b^{2}\imag^{2}\\
  &= a^{2} + b^{2}.
\end{align*}
A vertically centered equation number:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  \abs{a + b\imag}
  &= \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}},\\
  \abs{a + b\imag}^{2}
  &= a^{2} + b^{2},\\
  \abs{a + b\imag}^{2}
  &= (a + b\imag)(a + b\imag)\\
  &= (a + b\imag)(a - b\imag)\\
  &= a^{2} + b^{2}\imag^{2}\\
  &= a^{2} + b^{2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note: The fifth `=` is wrong; it should be `a^{2} - b^{2}\imag^{2}`.

Comment: The OP has an italic “i” and I find it arbitrary using a different notation. An italic “i” for the imaginary unit is common and *correct* in most fields of mathematics. Using `\mathit` in the definition is incorrect either.

Comment: @egreg Okay. How would you define `\img`? I'll change it according to your suggestion.

Comment: It's either `\mathrm{i}` (which I totally dislike) or simply `i`. So `\newcommand{\img}{i}` or `\newcommand{\img}{\mathrm{i}}`

Comment: Okay. I'll change it to `i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
|a+bi|  &=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\ 
|a+bi|^2&=a^2+b^2\\
|a+bi|^2&=(a+bi)(a+bi)\\
        &=(a+bi)(a-bi)\\
        &=a^2+b^2i^2\\
        &=a^2+b^2
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```